Save the Instance of the screen while navigating in Jetpack compose, Voyager Library?
I have got an scenario here! For example, In Screen A I called an API and fetched list, and when clicked on item of the list, i pushed to Screen B. when i come back from B to A, the API is called once again in Screen A, which i don't want. What i want here is that, it should save the previous instance of Screen A, just like in Activities. Anyone could hep me here?

Can you please share a [mcve] showing how that happens?
